# how to create dummy map with splash for avoid initial map loading in android

Tags: android, google-maps, splash-screen, supportmapfragment

**how to avoid initial google map loader like delay to first time open map activity in android**

*i am using map activity in my app. but i am not comfortable to initial map loader because it was irritating my end user. please help me*

*i have idea like create dummy map splash activity in my app but i dint know how to execute*

Can anyone tell me what is going on here? Thanks! and how to solve it.

**i am using code like this**

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

Comment: You can create a branded start screen with a background image.

Comment: i know but how to create with map fragment and how to connect it

Comment: Load the map during the startup screen. End the startup screen on load completion. So it will reveal the loaded map on close.

Comment: any example please

Comment: Google is a goldmine for tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use the map on the first screen I would consider using map lite mode. More about it you can find [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/lite). In short, it's a striped version of the Google maps, that has some basic features, but it's much lighter. It's great for usage in lists, and other places where it has to show fast.

Comment: thank you vladimir i try it